# First non blanck cell on the left

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My data are:

[image]

I'm looking to compute the amount to pay at the pay days:
[image]

I have a first solution:
[image]

"Amount due" is equal to the amount due previously, plus the amount of the period, minus the amount payed previouly.

```
D5=C5+D2-C6
```

Is it possible to get the same result with a formula, without the extra lines? (ie computing line 3 just with lines 1 and 2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter

```
=IF(C5,SUM($B6:C6)-SUM($B7:B7),"")
```

in `C7` and drag/copy to the right:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`=SUM(B2,MULTIPLY(A3,A1))`

again this is sheets sorry but the table should reflect the same values that you have,
I changed the TRUE but i'm sure you can do a bool if true 1 else 0 then multiply by that value

[image]

Comment: see edit, I sould be able to compute line 3 with line 1 and 2, not using my extra lines

Comment: amended, hopefully this helps.